# Get Count of rows with value true from a database in android kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, boolean, android-sqlite

I have a database, with names and true or false values.
I have for example 10 rows and four of them have got the value "true".

```
name | value  
-------------  
1    | false  
2    | true  
3    | false  
4    | true  
5    | false  
6    | false  
7    | true  
8    | false  
9    | false  
10   | true
```

my try is:

```
val c = db!!.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY value HAVING value = \"true\"", arrayOf())  
c.moveToNext()  
Log.e("OUTPUT", c.toString())
```

but the log I will get is:
`E/OUTPUT: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@b0b20ea`

So my question is, how to get the countnumber as a usable Integer value?

Comment: Your query seems wrong. If you want to count the number of `true` lines you should simply use: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE value = "true";`. If it doesn't work, try `value IS true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First correct your query like this:

```
val c = db!!.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE value = 'true'"
```

because you don't want to group by value but count the rows of the tables that contain the value `'true'`.
I assume that the column `value` contains strings.
If it contains booleans then the query should be:

```
val c = db!!.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE value"
```

Then you can extract the value of the 1st and only column of the cursor by `c.getInt(0)`:

```
Log.e("OUTPUT", c.getInt(0).toString())
```

Comment: Jeah now it is working. The query works with `\"` as well with `'` this does not make a different, but i changed it anyway and delete the `GROUP BY`. So thank you. But the second one works very good. Thank you.